# Cross browser data visualization alternative to Protovis?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

I built a chart similar to: http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/antibiotics-burtin.html using svgweb to make it work in IE8.  The quality is not that great and interaction is difficult to code.

Does anyone know of a cross-browser data visualization library that would be easier to work with yet achieve the same results (wedges of differing widths and lengths, json or csv driven data source, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

There's always [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/). Many of the Protovis examples have been ported to use D3, and interaction is easier to code. It uses SVG, so you'll still need to do something special to deal with browsers that don't support SVG.

Comment: @SultanShakir -- I'm glad it helped. If you like the answer, you might consider accepting it and/or upvoting it. Thanks!